# Access list from another class c#

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have created two classes for my program using c#,The first one "PayRecordSettings" reads a CSV file (using CSV helper) that has 5 columns. The second class "createPayRecord" should take the list and create a sublist for each column. I managed to read the CSV file and call it from the Main and it displays the data but I haven't figured out how to take the data and pass it to other classes. This is my code

```cs
public class CsvImporter
{
    public static List<PayRecordSettings> ImportPayRecords()
    {
        using (var path = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Import\\data.csv"))
        {
            using (var csvRead = new CsvReader(path, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvRead.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvSettingsMap>();
                var PayRecord = csvRead.GetRecords<PayRecordSettings>().ToList();
                return PayRecord;
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<PayRecordSettings> createPayRecord()
    {            
            foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(details.Hours + " hours" + details.Rate);
        }

        return ImportPayRecords;
    }
}

public class CsvSettingsMap : ClassMap<PayRecordSettings>
{
    public CsvSettingsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EmployeeId).Name("EmployeeId");
        Map(m => m.Hours).Name("Hours");
        Map(m => m.Rate).Name("Rate");
        Map(m => m.Visa).Name("Visa");
        Map(m => m.YearToDate).Name("YearToDate");
    }
}

public class PayRecordSettings
{

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public string Visa { get; set; }
    public string YearToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make empty cells equal to `0`?

I have updated my code based on Fildor comments. I have to report that the it works most of it. The CSV Helper settings didnt add a 0 when there is a empty cell. I have another question, **from the method PayRecordsettings** once I called the list how can I store this in new sublists? if I have 5 variables I would like to store a complete column of the CSV in a new list.

```cs
public static List<PayRecordSettings> createPayRecord()
{
    var payRecords = ImportPayRecords();
    foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(details.Hours);
    }
    
    return payRecords;
}   /* I would like to create a new list of Employee
                                        list of Hours
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `ImportPayRecords` is a method but is used like a property. Perhaps PayRecordSettings should be a `record`, by the way

Comment: Bit OT: rethink your naming. Think about somebody that does not know your code/program. So name your things that this person can understand as fast as possible what cour code does.  i read your first line and what you say is: I built a CSV importer. But I think the fact that data comes from CSV is not relevant for the functionality of the program.

Comment: Your description does not match your code: _"the first one "PayRecordSettings" reads and CSV file"_ - No, it does not. _"The second class "createPayRecord" "_ - Tat's not a class.

Comment: _"Is there a way to make empty cells equal to 0?"_ What's the documented behavior of CSVHelper? Can you annotate the model properties, maybe?

Comment: Could you please help with a [mcve]? Also, please tell us what packages you're using so we can run your code.

Comment: Your naming and convention is a bit all over the place. C# naming 101: `PublicVariables`, `_privateAndProtectedVariables`, `localVariables`, `MethodsAndProperties`, use plurals for variables that are collections, suffix classes that represent a collection with `Collection`, do not use plurals for class names. `var payRecords`, `class PayRecordSetting` or `class PayRecordConfiguration`, `PayRecordSetting detail in payRecordSettings` etc

Comment: If you are using the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), I found, then there are [Annotations](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/) and you can make Columns [optional](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/optional-maps/). For those, I'd set default values in the model class.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you've posted looks like it is missing some stuff. You use variables that not have been created like `ImportPayRecords` and `payRecords` in your `createPayRecord`-method.

To accomplish what you want to do, you need to pass your data as a parameter to you function like so:

```
public static void CreatePayRecord(IList<PayRecordSettings> payRecords)
{      

    foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(details.Hours + " hours" + details.Rate);
    }

}
```

Another tip, stick to the recommended [naming-conventions of C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) and also try to find more descriptive names for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

## Is there a way to make empty cells equal to 0?

If I read the docs correctly, it should work something like this:

```
public class PayRecordSettings
{

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Optional]
    public double Hours { get; set; } = 0.0;
    [Optional]
    public double Rate { get; set; } = 0.0;
    public string Visa { get; set; }
    public string YearToDate { get; set; }
}

public class CsvSettingsMap : ClassMap<PayRecordSettings>
{
    public CsvSettingsMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: Haven't tested this! So, take with a grain of salt.*

## "...but I havent figure out how to take the data and pass it to another classes"

You are mixing up some terms here:

```
public class CsvImporter  // <- THIS is a class
{
    // This is a (static) method
    public static List<PayRecordSettings> ImportPayRecords()
    {
       
        using (var path = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Import\\data.csv"))
        {
            using (var csvRead = new CsvReader(path, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvRead.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvSettingsMap>();
                var PayRecord = csvRead.GetRecords<PayRecordSettings>().ToList();
                return PayRecord;
            }
        }
    }

    // This is another static method.
    public static List<PayRecordSettings> createPayRecord()
    {   
        // this makes no sense: `payRecords` does not exist here.         
        foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(details.Hours + " hours" + details.Rate);
        }
        
        // makes no sense, neither. If at all, it should be `ImportPayRecords()`.
        return ImportPayRecords;
    }
}
```

So, to fix your second method, try this:

```
public static List<PayRecordSettings> CreatePayRecord()
{   
    var payRecords = ImportPayRecords();
    foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(details.Hours + " hours" + details.Rate);
    }
    
    return payRecords;
}
```

Mind that there is a dependency here between the two Methods, which is ... well ... let's say "suboptimal". Also `CreatePayRecord` doesn't actually do much creation. So you may want to refactor to using `ImportPayRecords` to get the list of model instances and maybe something like this to print them out:

```
public static void PrintPayRecords(IEnumerable<PayRecordSettings> payRecords)
{   
    foreach (PayRecordSettings details in payRecords)
    {
        // Sticking to your format, but looks kinda weird.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} hours{1}", details.Hours, details.Rate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fildor, your comments really helped me. The CSV helper settings didnt add a 0 to empty cells, but the rest of the code worked perfectly, How can I create a new sublist for each category . Lets say I would like to have a new list with only ID items and another one with only Hours.

Answer (score 0):

**First issue:** Getting defaulting empty cells to 0.

You can use `.Default()` for a default value if the field is empty.

Also, for your map class you don't need `.Name("EmployeeId")` if the name of the property is already "EmployeeId".  It will automatically assume that is the name. If you received a CSV file that had a heading of "EmpId" then you would need `Map(m => m.EmployeeId).Name("EmpId")`

```cs
public class CsvSettingsMap : ClassMap<PayRecordSettings>
{
    public CsvSettingsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EmployeeId);
        Map(m => m.Hours).Default(0);
        Map(m => m.Rate).Default(0);
        Map(m => m.Visa);
        Map(m => m.YearToDate);
    }
}
```

**Second issue:** From the method PayRecordsettings once I called the list how can I store this in new sublists? if I have 5 variables I would like to store a complete column of the CSV in a new list.

I'm really having difficulty understanding what you are looking to do.  Could you give some sample data that would be in the PayRecordSettings and then some examples of how you want the sublist data to look like?  Were you looking to output it into a new CSV file?